# Symfony2 Sonata project Internal Error on production

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, dev-to-production

i run my SM2 project_sonata on dev & prod localhost mode and it works well, but when i change to my website i get the error 500 :

```
Sonata Project - Internal Error

No site available
```

Comment: Have you cleared the cache and installed assets?

Comment: what missed is to update route with my website's url:
 sonata:page:update-core-routes        Update core routes, from routing files to page manager

Comment: You can add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what missed is to update routes with the website's url:

`sonata:page:update-core-routes --site=website.com`

```
 sonata:page:create-snapshots --site=website.com
```

Update core routes, from routing files to page manager 
Create a snapshots of all pages available

Comment: You can accept your own answer in order to *close* this question.